# How to make number to be counting down each second

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have this code to do this task: if no activity from user (mousemove and keypress) for 10 seconds then display a dialog (Jquery UI dialog) to warn and let user know they will be redirected to another page in the next 5 seconds unless they do something. How do I make the "**5**" in "You will be automatically redirected to ... after 5 seconds." to be counting down as 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 => then redirect ?

```
<script>
        // Set timeout variables.
        var timoutWarning = 10000; // Display warning in 10 seconds.
        var timoutNow = 15000; // Timeout in 15 seconds
        var logoutUrl = 'http://google.com'; // URL to redirect to.

        var warningTimer;
        var timeoutTimer;

        // Start timers.
        function StartTimers() {
            warningTimer = setTimeout("IdleWarning()", timoutWarning);
            timeoutTimer = setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", timoutNow);
        }

        // Reset timers.
        function ResetTimers() {
            clearTimeout(warningTimer);
            clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
            StartTimers();
            $("#timeout").dialog('close');
        }

        // Show idle timeout warning dialog.
        function IdleWarning() {
            $("#timeout").dialog({
                modal: true
            });            
        }

        // redirect the user.
        function IdleTimeout() {
            window.location = logoutUrl;
        }       

    </script>
```

html

```
<style>
    #timeout {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<body onload="StartTimers();" onmousemove="ResetTimers();" onclick="ResetTimers();">
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="DoNothing">
    <asp:Button ID="DoNothing" runat="server" Enabled="false" Style="display: none;" />
    <div class="page-container">
        <div class="container">

            Hold your mouse and don't press any key for 10 seconds, an dialog alert will be displayed.
            <div id="timeout">
                <h1>Session About To Timeout</h1>
                <p>
                    You will be automatically redirected to google after 5 seconds.<br />
                    To stay on this page move your mouse or press any key.
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the "5" within the paragraph here? ("You will be automatically redirected to google after **5** seconds.")

Comment: You have several errors on the page: `Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'`

Comment: @Shaggy Yes that is the 5 I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vano's suggestion of a jQuery plugin is good, and there's no reason not to use that. If you want to do it yourself, though, the code should be pretty simple:

```
var timer = -1; //so the timer doesn't start until everything is rendered

setInterval(function() {
    timer--;
    if (!timer) {
        window.location = logoutUrl;
    } else if (timer <= 5) {
        $('#timeout').html("Redirecting in " + timer + " seconds");        
    }
}, 1000);

$(document).on('ready keypress mousemove focus click scroll', function() {
    timer = 15;
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jvvgepo4/

Comment: I'd love to use that plugin but problem as I commented in his answer was it only give the option to continue staying by clicking to the button, where I want when user move mouse/click mouse or use keyboard they can stay as well. Your code is simple and works better, it also avoid the `<body onload="StartTimers();" onmousemove="ResetTimers();" onclick="ResetTimers();">`  => this make the  `ResetTimers()` stopped working after the JqueryUI dialog appeared for the first time, meaning the dialog keep appearing after 10 seconds  no matter what you do.

Comment: what `$(document).on('ready keypress mousemove focus',` does and `if (!timer)` means what?

Comment: another question, when the time is up, the page is not redirecting immediately but it closes the JqueryUI dialog first and then redirect, how do I make it redirect on-time while the dialog is still open (like this: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-idle-timeout/example-dialog.htm)?

Comment: It means that the timer starts when the page loads (`ready`), resets itself every time someone presses a button (`keypress`), moves the mouse (`mousemove`), or selects a form field (`focus`). `focus` is probably redundant, but it shouldn't hurt anything. I'm just unsure of how well this will capture touch events on a mobile device. You might want to test it on a phone and maybe add some more events.

Comment: `window.location = logoutUrl` should make it redirect immediately. Is that not happening? By the way, I edited the list of events to include `click` and `scroll`. Again, possibly redundant, but it won't hurt.

Comment: this, I am making a gif image that shows you the problem. Basically it close the dialog first so you basically go back to the page then it redirect (even it quick but still noticeable). In here you can see the page redirect immediately while the dialog is still open: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-idle-timeout/example-dialog.htm

Comment: Here the the HTML demo: http://pastebin.com/ckZiLAJp you can see it yourself of what I mean, it always close the dialog first before redirecting to other page.

Comment: When I tested it in my browser, redirecting to google.com violated the [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Try running it with your JavaScript console open to see any errors. If you get a "cross-origin policy" or similar error, try some of the workarounds in [this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3076648/399649)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jquery-idleTimeout](https://github.com/philpalmieri/jquery-idleTimeout)

Here is the [demo](http://www.philpalmieri.com/js_sandbox/timedLogout/)

Usage example:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
           $(document).idleTimeout({
             inactivity: 10000, 
             noconfirm: 5000,
             dialogTitle: 'title',
             dialogText: 'warning text',
             redirect_url: 'http://google.com',
           });
          });
```

**Edit:**

To add countdown functionality, you can use [jquery-idle-timeout](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-idle-timeout)

It has *onCountdown* event. [Here](http://jsbin.com/yogogekegi/1/) is the working example.

Comment: How does it determine when to "timeout", does it include mousemove and key/button press?

Comment: Yes it track mouse and keyboard.

Comment: I just see the demo, nicely done but see, but I didnt see the option that counting down the seconds left before it redirects, that's why I asked this question :(

Comment: Here is demo: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-idle-timeout/example-dialog.htm

Comment: Very nice plugin, for now I just want to stick with my function because on the plugin you showed me, user have to click to the button to keep staying, but I want that user can just move the mouse or press any thing => the alert goes away and they are back on. Have any idea how to make the counting down number on the code work?